# Runtime.getRuntime().exec() output differ from executing a command line program directly

Tags: java, command-line

Running

```
/usr/bin/mediainfo --Inform='Video;%Duration%' /home/daniel/upload/videos/4/f/6/e/f/4f6ef2e0d67c4.flv
```

from terminal gives me this output

> 903520

And running this in java

```
        Process p1;
    try {
        p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/mediainfo --Inform='Video;%Duration%' /home/daniel/upload/videos/4/f/6/e/f/4f6ef2e0d67c4.flv");

        BufferedReader input1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p1.getInputStream()));
        String line1;
        while ((line1 = input1.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("-"+line1);
        }
        input1.close();         

        p1.waitFor();               


    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Results in

```
-General
-Complete name : /home/daniel/upload/videos/4/f/6/e/f/4f6ef2e0d67c4.flv
-Format                                   : Flash Video
-File size                                : 62.0 MiB
-Duration                                 : 15mn 3s
-Overall bit rate                         : 576 Kbps
-Tagging application       : Yet Another Metadata Injector for FLV - Version 1.4
-
-Video
-Format                                   : AVC
-Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
-Format profile                           : High@L2.0
-Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
-Format settings, ReFrames                : 4 frames
-Codec ID                                 : 7
-Duration                                 : 15mn 3s
-Bit rate                                 : 512 Kbps  
(much more here) ...
```

**How do I get my desired output (903520) from Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd) ?**

*edit: fixed formatting*

Comment: Hint - check your question in the preview window before posting. That formatting doesn't look healthy to me...

Comment: Without knowing much about what `/usr/bin/mediainfo` does, is it clear to you how the arguments must have been interpreted to cause the second set of output?  This seems especially weird if it would usually simply output a six-digit number.

Comment: If the output of one command differs from the output of another, then either (a) the command lines are different, or (b) the environment (current working directory, environment variables, etc.) are different. (Or (a) and (b) both, obviously.) Can you put an `echo` in front of the `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` command line and share the captured results? In that way, we can determine if the two command lines really are the same, as you think they are. If they *are* the same, we'll check the environment next. I suspect that the issue is that `%Duration%` is not being expanded as it would in a "n

Comment: An echo? How do I do this?

Comment: The output from mediainfo with that set of arguments should return the length of the movie in nano seconds. So a six-digit number is what I expect for a clip ~15mins

Comment: Think I know what you mean. 
String[] cmd = {"echo", "/usr/bin/mediainfo", "--Inform='Video;%Duration%'", "/home/daniel/upload/videos/4/f/6/e/f/4f6ef2e0d67c4.flv"};
    Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
gives /usr/bin/mediainfo --Inform='Video;%Duration%' /home/daniel/upload/videos/4/f/6/e/f/4f6ef2e0d67c4.flv

Comment: If this would be DOS/Windows, then `%VAR%` would be replaced by `cmd.exe`. But in this case all the paths are Unix-style. So `%XYZ%` would not be changed by the shell.

Comment: @daker, that's it. What does the output of `Process#getOutputStream()` look like for the created `Process`? That will be the value of the command line as executed by the underlying `Runtime`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The commandline shell does some magic for you which `Runtime.exec()` does **NOT** for you.

In this case I guess, that the shell interprets (and omits) the `'` marks in your commandline.

So please try this version, where the `'` have been removed and the commandline has been splitted into parts by hand (another common issue):

```
String[] args = new String[]{
    "/usr/bin/mediainfo",
    "--Inform=Video;%Duration%",
    "/home/daniel/upload/videos/4/f/6/e/f/4f6ef2e0d67c4.flv"
};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args);
```

Comment: *arrghh* One Wasted hour. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Note that there is a `Runtime.exec(String)` **and** a `Runtime.exec(String[])`.
Have you tried the second method, just to make sure the string command is being interpreted the way it should?

From the docs:

```
public Process exec(String command)
             throws IOException
```

> Executes the specified string command in a separate process. (...)

---

```
public Process exec(String[] cmdarray)
             throws IOException
```

> Executes the specified command and arguments in a separate process. (...)

---

You may try:

```
String[] myArgs = new String[]{
    "/usr/bin/mediainfo",
    "--Inform='Video;%Duration%'",
    "/home/daniel/upload/videos/4/f/6/e/f/4f6ef2e0d67c4.flv"
};

Process p1;
try {
    p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(myArgs);
        ...
}
```